# C++ construct a tuple from elements with indices that are NOT in a given index_sequence

Tags: c++11

I already have a template that given a `tuple` and an `index_sequence` can create a new `tuple` having the elements indexed by that sequence. This function template is called `project`

I figured if I can somehow calculate the difference of two `index_sequence`s then I'm done: I pass to `project` the difference of `make_index_sequence<original_tuple_t>` and the given one, which is assumed sorted and unique.

Is this a good approach? Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: Is the filter sequence sorted?

Comment: Yes we can assume that it is sorted and unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation.

First we'll start off with a simple trait to add a `std::size_t` onto the front of a `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <std::size_t First, typename Seq>
struct sequence_cat;

template <std::size_t First, std::size_t... Seq>
struct sequence_cat <First, std::index_sequence<Seq...>> {
    using type = std::index_sequence<First, Seq...>;   
};

//helper
template <std::size_t First, typename Seq>
using sequence_cat_t = typename sequence_cat<First, Seq>::type;
```

Now we'll define a trait called `not_in_sequence` which will recursively check the fronts of two `std::index_sequence`s and filter off any from the first which occur in the second:

```
//empty first sequence
template <class First, class Second>
struct not_in_sequence {
    using type = std::index_sequence<>; 
};

//helper
template <class First, class Second>
using not_in_sequence_t = typename not_in_sequence<First, Second>::type;

//filter and recurse
template <std::size_t... First, std::size_t... Second, 
          std::size_t FirstHead, std::size_t SecondHead>
struct not_in_sequence <std::index_sequence<FirstHead, First...>,
                        std::index_sequence<SecondHead, Second...>> {
    using seq1 = std::index_sequence<First...>;
    using seq2 = std::index_sequence<Second...>;

    using type = 
        std::conditional_t<
            (FirstHead == SecondHead),
            not_in_sequence_t<seq1, seq2>,
            sequence_cat_t<
                FirstHead, 
                not_in_sequence_t<seq1, sequence_cat_t<SecondHead, seq2>>
            >
         >;   
}; 
//empty second sequence
template <std::size_t... First, std::size_t FirstHead>
struct not_in_sequence <std::index_sequence<FirstHead, First...>,
                        std::index_sequence<>> {
    using type = std::index_sequence<FirstHead, First...>;   
};
```

You can use `not_in_sequence_t` like so:

```
not_in_sequence_t<std::make_index_sequence<3>, std::index_sequence<0,2>>
//same as std::index_sequence<1>
```

There might be some edge-cases I've missed, but feel free to edit this as you like.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c811f65637b0e9a8)